# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When i execute this query i get this error :

```
return (from i in _ctx.TestPackages
   where i.Id==TestPackageId

   select new  ViewTestPackageState
   {
       Id = i.Id,
       PackageNumber = i.PackageNumber,
       ReInstatement = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Reinstatment")[0],
       ReInstatementReportNumber = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Reinstatment")[1],
       ReInstatementSubmitDateTime = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Reinstatment")[2],

       TestReportNumber = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Test")[1],
       TestState = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Test")[0],
       TestSubmitDateTime = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Test")[2],

       CleanReportNumber = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Clean")[1],
       CleanSubmitDateTime = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Clean")[2],
       CleaningState = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Clean")[0],

       Drying = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Drying")[0],
       DryingReportNumber = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Drying")[1],
       DryingSubmitDateTime = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Drying")[2],

       Flushing = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Flushing")[0],
       FlushingReportNumber = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Flushing")[1],
       FlushingSubmitDateTime = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Flushing")[2],

       LineCheckReportNumber = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "LineCheck")[1],
       LineCheckState = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "LineCheck")[0],
       LineCheckSubmitDateTime = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "LineCheck")[2],

       Size = i.Size.ToString(),
       TestPackageOrder = i.TestPackageOrder,

   }).ToList();
```

The error :LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

I know the problem is because of the query and the query should be executed before select statement ,so my question is how can i execute this query before select ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the query and then select object from the result

```
var result = (from i in _ctx.TestPackages
   where i.Id==TestPackageId).ToList();

return(result.Select( new ViewTestPackageState{...}));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var rawList = (from i in _ctx.TestPackages where i.Id==TestPackageId).ToList();

return rawList.Select(i => new ViewTestPackageState
       {
           Id = i.Id,
           PackageNumber = i.PackageNumber,
           ReInstatement = ReturnTestPackageState(i.Id, "Reinstatment")[0],
           // etc
```